# How to convert a groupby().mean() into a callable object?

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

I have the following very simple model in which I encounter an error message while I run it. The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "mltest.py", line 63, in <module>
pred = B.predict(ms,r[0:10])
File "mltest.py", line 54, in predict
return map(self.means['score'][X], X)
TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable
```

The models structures as below:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin
import pandas as pd

class MeanClassifier(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def fit(self, X, y):
        self.name = X
        self.scores = y  
        self.data = pd.DataFrame({"name": self.name, "score": self.scores})
        #print(self.data)
        self.means = self.data.groupby(["name"]).mean()
        #print(self.means)
        return self

    def predict(self, X):
        return map(self.means['score'][X], X)
```

Then I have a list of X (names)and y (scores)for model fitting and prediction. As I am testing my code, I just use the same data for model fitting and prediction.

```
names = ["John", "Mary", "Suzie", "John", "John", "Mary", "Suzie"]
scores = [80, 70, 75, 90, 92, 82, 88]
B = MeanClassifier()
Bfit = B.fit(names, scores)
Bpred = B.predict(names)
```

Obviously, the error comes from the datatype after I employ `groupby(['name']).mean()`. This object is not callable and therefore map does not work here. Could anyone give me a suggestion how to solve this problem? Thank you!!

Comment: ``data.groupby(['name']).mean()`` will return a DataFrame or Series, so this is indeed not callable. In `map`, you need to provide a function, not a dataframe/series. Please provide a minimal reproducible example and explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you. I added values in the lists of names and scores. They are in the bottom code part. I hope they would be helpful decipher what I am attempting to do. names are X and scores are y in the model. I am trying to use the model MeanClassifier to predict (in this case, actually, report) the meanscores of a list of people with names in `names`.  Please let me know if I should further clarify anything. Thank you.

Comment: I also imported pandas and BaseEstimator and ClassifierMixin in the code. I hope it works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your estimator class, `self.means` is a DataFrame with index `name` and a single column called `score`. Change your `predict` function to

```
def predict(self, X):
    return self.means.loc[X, 'score']
```

`.loc` takes an index label (or list thereof) and a column label (or list thereof), so the above returns a Series (because you're accessing one column) with the values in the column `score` for all the names in `X`.